# Inserting an string variable between spans

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put my string variable named "bringMe" into this line of code.

Please help...

```
var filler = "<span><font color='#FF0000'>***** bringMe Variable *****</font></span>";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**.

> **Template literals**: Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions
>
> ```js
> let bringMe = "My variable"
> let filler = `<span><font color='#FF0000'>${bringMe}</font></span>`;
> console.log(filler);
> ```

Comment: one more question how that spamming answer knows your name and seems related and accurate???

Comment: he means just a copy paste edit of his answer, to get points. knows his name cause its a human doing it and can read...

Comment: @tgkprog what do you mean?

Comment: Why should someone wants to get points on StackOverflow ... does he make money ???

Comment: Social points help our feelings. not everything is about money. part of life is about feeling useful and liked

Answer (score 2):

Use template literals as shown by Maheer. To expand, the difference is using the backtick "`" instead of the standard single/double quotation marks ("/').

Using template literals allows you to embed expressions and have multi-line strings.

For more information, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals.

Answer (score 1):

Use + operator and "" to add (concatenate )strings

```js
var filler = "<span><font color='#FF0000'>" +'bringMe'+ " Variable *****</font></span>";
console.log(filler)
```

If bringMe is a variable

```js
var bringMe="string"
var filler = "<span><font color='#FF0000'>" +bringMe+ " Variable *****</font></span>";
    console.log(filler)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this :

```
`<span><font color='#FF0000'>${bringMe}</font></span>`
```